# How I can drive my flyback transformer which has 10 pins?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

It has 10 pins the details shown below, but I have no idea to run it with simple driving circuit. If you guys will me it will really helpful for me and also share after tested with driving circuit how I can integrate it with this circuit.

[image: flyback transformer][image: flyback transformer1][image: power supply circuit]

Comment: You need a datasheet of the flyback transformer. You need to know more about the transformer than only the number of pins.

Comment: This is a disaster waiting to happen. If you have to ask this question and also post pictures of a transformer that looks very suspicious indeed then, you are not nearly experienced enough to build or test this circuit.

Answer (score 6):

Mains AC circuit and a plan to build it using unknown parts? The only rational response here is to say STOP! Life is already too short!

Nobody here cannot decide if the photo presents something which fits the shown schematic, no matter he might have seen something with the same number of pins, colors and size. One should have the transformer in his hands. And that one should know what he does.

I cannot see proper insulation worth connecting to mains AC (through the rectifier). To be able to say can it be used in a flyback SMPS for the wanted voltages, max. output current and plausible operating frequency I should know also the wire thicknesses, winding ratios and at least one winding inductance.

In flyback usage the core saturation is fatal. I should know how much current the primary winding stands without saturation. After finding all details above I could select proper SMPS operational parameters and may be able to design the right circuit, even be able to check if the shown circuit could be used.

YouTube is not the right place to search mains AC projects, not at least for those who do not know what they do. Get a ready to use power supply and stay alive.

Late addition: The video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lngyl-0J-zk where your schematic is taken from is not a construction project. It's intended to show how poorly constructed a low cost power supply can be, no matter there can be printed whatever performance ratings and certificate stamps on it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know the frequency, power level, and input-output voltages this transformer is designed for.

Judging from the pictures, the isolation level doesn't seem to be high.

You have a transformer with no technical details or datasheet whatsoever.

<sup>NOTE: The only thing you can do at this stage is to find the dots using a signal/function generator and a scope but it'll be a waste of time because you'll need the other details which don't seem to be available.</sup>